# Need to validate with range and by pass validation function with session value if user want to enter value beyond range

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jsp

I have multiple input type text  on jsp form for each the range is defined to the next input type textbox i want to validate with the defined range and if the value beyond the range validation function ask for pop confirmation if user enter userid in text that compare with session value ie 'user' then the validation function allow user to submit form with return true and not ask again for that filed validate  .how can i achieve this using javascript function.any other way that can i achieve same using javascript .Request you to Suggest Option with example code.

JavaScript code:-

```
if(document.getElementById('pH'+formid).value !=0)
{ 
var user;
var value=document.getElementById('pH'+formid).value;
var maxmin=document.getElementById('pHspecf'+formid).value.split('-');
var max=maxmin[0];
var min=maxmin[1];

if(value<min||value>mix)
    {
    alert("max-"+max+" min-"+min+"    value of parameter-"+value);
    var c=confirm("Entered Value Beyond the Specification Range.\n DO you Still Want To continue Press Yes..!");

    if (c==true)
     {
        var person=prompt("Please enter your Username","Your User name");
        if (person!=null)
          {user=person;
            alert("Hello "+person+" Your Request Is Accepted..!");

     }else{
          document.getElementById('pH'+formid).style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
            document.getElementById('pH'+formid).focus();
            return false;
      }

  }
else
  {
    document.getElementById('pH'+formid).focus();
    return false;
  }


    }

}
```

Comment: java-script will not communicate with sessions.

Comment: Every text box will have limited character's. If the user want to enter more characters then user should enter his user-id in a popup box?  If user-id matches with the session variable user then it should allow more characters? Is this your question?

Comment: Every text box will have limited range max min for integer type value. If the user want to enter more beyond the range then user should enter his user-id in a popup box? If user-id matches with the session variable user then it should allow the entered value no matter it is > then or < or not betwwen range.  this is  myquestion?!

Comment: Why don't you just save session variable in javascript and then let him/her enter their id and check just via javascript... Load session variable in the jsp with scriptlet/EL and then when user gives you their id just check it with variable you set in javaScript and then do whatever you want...

Comment: yes Shalin thanks for your response. this question is ask for 2 day before but am not getting any predictable answer here rather then your .but i have did same early thanks.